# Does anyone know how to use TF Quantum with real hardware data?

Tags: programming, cirq, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning, tfq

I'm currently trying to embed a tensorflow model for denoising measurements as a tensorflow quantum model, and at some point I'd like for this to be able to run on hardware. After reading through all the tutorials and relevant portions of the source code such as [sampled_expectation.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/quantum/blob/d7dd484a9793614d05698149e567c9ec3d40c30d/tensorflow_quantum/python/layers/circuit_executors/sampled_expectation.py) and [sample.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/quantum/blob/ca4d0cb2ac484a7a24d42094a4649fd8aea9f3b0/tensorflow_quantum/python/layers/circuit_executors/sample.py). The only available backends for these functions are 'noiseless' and 'noisy'. But in reading the tensorflow release paper, they say that these models can be deployed on real hardware. So how do I define a tensorflow-quantum layer that includes a result from a hardware, or simulated hardware execution?